# Getting rows with 'date_added' between two dates doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-contentresolver

I want to get the rows which have been added during the last weeks.

Here my actual code:

```
private static Cursor makeRecentlyAddedSongsCursor(Context context) {
    String[] sProjection = new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED};

    String MIN_DATE = String.format("dd/MM/yyyy", new Date().getTime() - ((long) PreferenceUtility.getRecentlyAddedTimespan(context) * 7L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L));
    String CURRENT_DATE = String.format("dd/MM/yyyy", new Date().getTime());

    String sSelection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED + Constants.Database.BETWEEN; //String BETWEEN = " BETWEEN ? AND ?";
    String[] sSelectionArgs = {MIN_DATE, CURRENT_DATE};

    return context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, sProjection, sSelection, sSelectionArgs, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED + Constants.Database.SORT_DESCENDING);
}
```

The error must be in the Selection Argument, because if I leave it away, all songs are shown, sorted correctly.

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED date time in long format.

Thus, you don't need to format your date in 'dd/MM/yyyy' format. This code should be do the job:

```
Long current = (new Date().getTime())/1000;
String currentDate = current.toString();
```

Otherwise, for formatting a date in 'dd/MM/yyyy' you should use a `DateFormat` like `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
  String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
```

`String.format` allows to format a string using a printf-style format string with %s, %d, %f, etc... Actually you can use it to print a date:

```
Calendar c = ...;
String s = String.format("Duke's Birthday: %1$tm %1$te,%1$tY", c);
```

For more information about printf-style format in Java you can go here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: Indeed, it due to the DATE_ADDED format... It is a long. I have updated my answer